# Form development optimization

Tags: optimization, automation, repeat

Like many web developers I do forms all the time. I found myself doing the same all the time: placing input fields, assigning a name to each, ajax the form, then create the php which involves to assign a $php var to each $_REQUEST['var'], escape and validate data, build the html and emailing the results...

So I find that 70% of the work I repetitive but I just can't duplicate a page and change the fields. I end up wasting more time reformatting, deleting and adding different fields than creating from scratch.

I started planing to program a "list of IDs to html+php" converter in which I'd input all the IDs and this would output the basic html and php. Then I thought: there's got to be thousands of developers that go through this, I'd be reinventing the wheel. So this is my question, I'm trying to find that wheel that somebody must have invented already.

I found this: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqform/ which does more or less what I'm looking for but it's an expensive solution and it has too much functionality for what I'd be using it.

**Which tools do you use to optimize repetitive task about html and php?**

Answer (score 0):

Creating forms using plain HTML is cumbersome and time consuming. The task will be much simpler if you use an open source form library. I use [Zend_Forms](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html) extensively. You could also look into the one provided by [EZ Components](http://ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/UserInput)

These form libraries allow you to specify various form elements, validators for each element and data filters (string tags, lowercasing etc...). Once you have specified these the library automatically handles the rendering of forms and further if there are errors it will renders the errors as well. Usually these libraries render the forms with certain predefined mark-up (HTML) but it's configurable as well.

If you start using one of these libraries you would save a lot of time while creating forms. In-fact I would suggest you to use a framework such as Zend or Symfony for your projects.

Comment: these forms are for small company website, the kind that have about 5/6 html and a small contact form... implementing a framework would be  pointless

Comment: @Juan: Zend components can be used independently of the framework.

Comment: almost all of the forms i want to optimize doing are in .htmls